# Differences between Linux Distribution for Meteor

Tags: linux, meteor, server

does it make any difference which Linux Distribution (Ubuntu,Debian,CentOS) i choose when i want to develope with Meteor/MeteorJS?

And do you have any recommendations?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only subtle differences between running Meteor on different Linux distributions. If you want to avoid surprises the best solution is to run exactly the same flavor of linux in development as later in production.

Recommendations would be based on personal preference and not on technical reasons, so you should be good to go with either of the supported systems.

Comment: Exactly what i wantet to hear, thanks.